# Finding all integer solutions of an equality

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

I want to generate all solutions of $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_{100}=6$ where $x_i$s are non-negative integers. Finding the number of such solutions is not difficult. But is there any easy way to get all solutions?

Comment: This is a straightforward programming exercise: go over all possible values of $x_1$ (from $0$ to $6$), then over all possible values of $x_2$ (from $0$ to $6-x_1$), and so on. Some minor optimizations are possible (once you get to $6$ then the rest of the $x_i$ are zero).

Comment: also, at least $94$ $x_i$'s will always be $0$.